# Error retrieving value textarea's value from form in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am new to Django. I am trying to create a simple form that has text area in it. I can't seem to retrieve the value from textarea

Here's my form:

```
<form method="POST" class="ui form" action="">
 {% csrf_token %}
 <div class="field">
  <label>Title</label>
  <input type="text" name="title"/>
  <label> Content</label>
  <textarea  rows="8" name="content" ></textarea>
 </div>
<button type="submit" class="ui primary button">Create</button>
</form>
```

Here's my how I handle the form

```
    def createArticle(request):
      if(request.method == 'POST'):
      form = ArticleForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
        title = form.cleaned_data['title']
        body = form.cleaned_data['content']
        username = request.session['email']
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
```

I am getting this error `KeyError at /create/article/
'content'` at this line `body = form.cleaned_data['content']`

Here's the content from my post request

`csrfmiddlewaretoken'CgCwDF1d03KGIxsmM2Z4hhStBRIxw9hlh1ACtYXpBWXLLvYJq2tfdO7lqds7EVxI'`

`title'dsadasdasdsadsadasdsadasdsadsad'`

`content'<p>sadasdsadasdasdasdsadasdasdsadsadsadasdsadsadsadsadsadsadsadasdasd</p>\r\n'`

I am guessing the `<p>` tag in `content` is what causing the error but I have no idea idea how to get rid of that.

Comment: No, the `p` tags should not affect it at all. Is the indentation in the code you have posted above correct - specifically the stuff below the `if` statement?

Comment: yes, it works just as I expected when I replace the line that cause error with `body = request.POST['content']`(but that also save the `p` tag in the database). The indentation may looks weird because I just copied and didn't format it.

Comment: Where is the definition of ArticleForm? The problem is there.

Comment: yes you're right, turns out I just need to change this `body = forms.Textarea()` to `body = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea())` and it works

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to define name and id attributes for the form, and also define a form attribute for the textarea whose value would be the value of the form's id attribute.

```
<form method="POST" class="ui form" action="" id="content" name="content">
 {% csrf_token %}
 <div class="field">
  <label>Title</label>
  <input type="text" name="title"/>
  <label> Content</label>
  <textarea  rows="8" form="content" ></textarea>
 </div>
<button type="submit" class="ui primary button">Create</button>
</form>
```